# Make Member Directory with SearchKit / FormBuilder which does not show all members

Tags: searchkit, directory, formbuilder

I have built a Member Directory using SearchKit with a SearchKit Table and filtered on the connected Form using the Contact Sort Name, which creates a user search box. I cannot see a way to prevent the user just hitting the "Search" button to yield the full list of members - I want to constrain users to only see records that match an entered search term. Is this possible?
Selecting "Required" for the text filter does not compel the user to enter text in the Search field.
Additionally, and perhaps an alternative, it would be nice to be able to force the Search results to limit to a maximum number of records, but I cannot see how to force such a limit either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an option available on the search kit display setting to auto-run or use the Search button. Selecting 'Auto-run' should load results automatically but with button the user will need to hit the button to display the results

HTH

Pradeep

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. I have also discovered the option to limit results on the Table setup!

Comment: So can you mark this as answered so that it will help others to solve if they face similar issue?